# symfony get parameters from parameters.yml

Tags: symfony, containers

Hello im trying to make a project that communicate with riot API. Im new in symfony and i found a very good bundle which inspired me, but in Services he injected whole container and i read that its not good idea to inject the whole container, but i really need to getParameter from parameters.yml
How can i did it ? Im also getting this error:

```
Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Controller\Service\ChampionService": argument "$container" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to one of its parents: interface "Psr\Container\ContainerInterface", or interface "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface".
```

My Service:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Service;
    use AppBundle\Controller\guzzleClient\GuzzleClient;
    use Psr\Log\InvalidArgumentException;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
    use AppBundle\Entity\Champion;

    class ChampionService
    {
        /**
         * @var GuzzleClient
         */
        private $guzzle;
        /**
         * @var Container
         */
        private $container;
        /**
         * Constructor
         * @param GuzzleClient $guzzle
         * @param Container $container
         */
        public function __construct(GuzzleClient $guzzle, Container $container) {
            $this->guzzle = $guzzle;
            $this->container = $container;
        }
        /**
         * Retrieves all the champions
         *
         * @param $region string
         * @param $freeToPlay boolean
         * @throws \Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Exception\InternalErrorException
         * @return array
         */
        public function getChampions($region, $freeToPlay = null) {
            $request = $this->container->getParameter('roots')['champion']['champions'];
            if($freeToPlay == null) {
                $champions = $this->guzzle->send($request, $region);
            } else {
                $champions = $this->guzzle->send($request, $region, array('freeToPlay' => $freeToPlay));
            }
            return $this->createChampions($champions->champions);
        }
        /**
         * Retrieves one champion
         *
         * @param integer $id the id of the champion
         * @param $region string
         * @throws \Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Exception\InternalErrorException
         * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Champion
         */
        public function  getChampionById($id, $region) {
            if(!is_int($id)) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('The "id" must be an int');
            }
            $request = $this->container->getParameter('roots')['champion']['championById'];
            $request = str_replace('{id}', $id, $request);
            $champion = $this->guzzle->send($request, $region);
            return $this->createChampion($champion);
        }
        /**
         * Create an array of champions
         *
         * @param array $champions an array of json object chamions
         * @return array
         */
        private function createChampions($champions) {
            $return = array();
            foreach($champions as $champion) {
                $return[] = $this->createChampion($champion);
            }
            return $return;
        }
        /**
         * Create a champion
         *
         * @param $object \stdClass
         * @return Champion
         */
        private function createChampion($object) {
            $champion = new Champion();
            $champion->setActive($object->active);
            $champion->setBotEnabled($object->botEnabled);
            $champion->setBotMmEnabled($object->botMmEnabled);
            $champion->setFreeToPlay($object->freeToPlay);
            $champion->setId($object->id);
            $champion->setRankedPlayEnabled($object->rankedPlayEnabled);
            return $champion;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Symfony version¿?

Comment: symfony version: 3.3.8

Comment: Check my Answer.. change Container to ContainerInterface..

Comment: Since roots is the only parameter you need, you should check the docs to see how to inject it.  That would eliminate the need to inject the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Other solution, in the service.yml**

```
services:
    your_service:
        class:  Your\Bundle\Service\YourService
        arguments: [%param1%, %param2%]
```

In the class

```
public function __construct($param1, $param2){}
```

*But you use container in the service, this is normal.*

Change

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
```

to

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
```

Example from my project in Symfony **V3.2** is **ContainerInterface**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class YourClassService {

/**
 * @var ContainerInterface
 */
protected $serviceContainer;


/**
 * @param ContainerInterface $serviceContainer
 */
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $serviceContainer)
{
   $this->serviceContainer = $serviceContainer;

   $param = $this->serviceContainer->getParameter('parameter');
}

}
```

In service.yml

```
services:
    your.class.service.api:
       class: YourClassService
       arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

Comment: So is as i have  in my project.

Comment: @Cuchi - Sadly, drive by downvoters are just a fact of life.  Like fleas.  Just ignore them.  Your solution is a bit general and it ignores the autowire portion of the error message.  But, leaving aside the service definition, actually is correct.

Answer (score -2):

Symfony3

```
 $this->getParameter('yourParameter');
```

Comment: What makes you think that ChampionService has a getParameter method?

Comment: ChampionService is a service created to him. For read the parameters need the container.

Comment: if your service class extends the Controller class you can get any parameter from parameters.yml